# Qt mapbox offline usage

Tags: c++, qt, qml, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am currently working on a Qt application where we need to load the planet map for full offline usage. I started using Qt Location Mapbox GL Plugin to play around with the map and everything works fine when the internet connection is present.

But according to our product requirements the internet connection will be extremely limited and most of times we will not have internet connection at all. So, we need to have a completely offline usage of mapboxgl in our Qt application. Is there any way to do that by setting some parameters of Mapbox GL Plugin that I have missed? Is it possible by exporting offline tiles from official mapbox [offline tool](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/bin) and stored them in a database?

Other suggestions or ideas on how to use an offline map in Qt are also welcome.

A link with all Qt Location Mapbox GL Plugin parameters.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/location-plugin-mapboxgl.html

Below you can find a basic example of using a mapbox map in Qt and Qml.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Window {
    width: Qt.platform.os == "android" ? Screen.width : 512
    height: Qt.platform.os == "android" ? Screen.height : 512
    visible: true

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "mapboxgl"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75) // Oslo
        zoomLevel: 14
    }
}
```

Comment: Could I kindly ask you some minimal example, so we can play with it and try to help?

Comment: @AdrianMaire I just added a minimal example on the original post and a link with Qt Location Mapbox GL Plugin information.

Comment: Did you tried to play with the cache values? they seems to fit exactly this purpose. `This cache can also be used for storing offline tiles, but the offline database must be populated using the offline tool. `

Comment: @AdrianMaire the cache values will work only if you will connect on internet at least for one time and they will be cached only the areas and zoom levels that you used on the first time. So, if you will try to zoom in at a specific area that is not being cached, then I suppose that you will not have the expected results.

Comment: Exactly, this is what I am asking how to generate all these possible tiles for planet map using the offline tool and store them in a database. Then, using the cache parameters I will be able to use the map offline.

Comment: In other posts I am reading about using MBTiles or MapBox Atlas product but since I have never been involved with offline map usage before, I am still confused what steps I have to follow.

Comment: Maybe you can just download (while inline) to see the cache structure, and use some python/js script to automatize the download for all the territory needed. I am pretty sure it must be a simple REST API saved in folders. Also, check the license, as Qt point that downloading huge terrain could be illegal.

Comment: @AdrianMaire thank you for your suggestion. I could start working on this and check how it goes. About Qt obligations I checked the Qt Location Mapbox GL Plugin and it's under [Mapbox terms of service](https://www.mapbox.com/legal/tos). I think that there aren't  limitations on downloading huge terrain data but I am not sure reading all these legal details.